# Executing of picture box paint event handler becomes slower and slower

Tags: c#, performance, gdi

excuse me for my bad english. I'm trying to draw a rotating lines on picturebox by setting Paint event handler on it in timer tick handler function:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Draw);//1
        foreach (Line line in lines)//array "lines" contains just 16 objects
        {
            //calculating new coordinates ...
        }
    }
```

The line, tagged with "1", is executing slower and slower in process of time. Here is the "Draw" function code below:

```
void Draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Line line in lines)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5f), line.P1, line.P2);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P1.X - 2.5f, line.P1.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P2.X - 2.5f, line.P2.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f), line.P1.X, line.P1.Y, 1, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f), line.P2.X, line.P2.Y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

Can you guys please tell me , how can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you ever remove the "draw" handler you add in your timer tick?? otherwise it could be doing 1 additional itteration for each tick so first time is 1, second time 2, 3rd time 3.. by the 1000th time its trying to do 1000

Comment: Seems you are adding your handler over and over again. In addition, you are not disposing any of your `Pen` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do  pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Draw);//1 in timer1_Tick. Do it once in your form load. Otherwise it will call Draw() many times per each Paint event and the number of calls will increase.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        foreach (Point line in lines)
        {
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5f), line.P1, line.P2);
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P1.X - 2.5f, line.P1.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P2.X - 2.5f, line.P2.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f), line.P1.X, line.P1.Y, 1, 1);
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f), line.P2.X, line.P2.Y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
```

If it wont show effect then add following line after loop

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart form solving the envent handler issue already pointed out in the other answers, I'd change a few things in your code.

First and foremost, why are you creating so many `Pen`s? Take them out of the loop:

```
void Draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5f);
    var redPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f);

    foreach (Line line in lines)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, line.P1, line.P2);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P1.X - 2.5f, line.P1.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P2.X - 2.5f, line.P2.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redPen, line.P1.X, line.P1.Y, 1, 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redPen, line.P2.X, line.P2.Y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Hmm, now, do notice that `Pen` implements `IDisposable`. Get into the habit of disposing these type of objects once your are done with them; this way you will be releasing the underlying unmanaged resources determinalistically and not when the `GC` decides to:

```
void Draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5f))
    using (var redPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f))
    {
        foreach (Line line in lines)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, line.P1, line.P2);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P1.X - 2.5f, line.P1.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P2.X - 2.5f, line.P2.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redPen, line.P1.X, line.P1.Y, 1, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redPen, line.P2.X, line.P2.Y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you could even consider caching the `Pen`s as instance variables;

```
class MyControl: ..., IDisposable
{
     private readonly Pen blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5f));
     private readonly Pen redPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f));

     void Draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         foreach (Line line in lines)
         {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, line.P1, line.P2);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P1.X - 2.5f, line.P1.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P2.X - 2.5f, line.P2.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redPen, line.P1.X, line.P1.Y, 1, 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(redPen, line.P2.X, line.P2.Y, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
         ....
         if (disposing)
         {
             ....
             blackPen.Dispose(;)
             redPen.Dispose();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: good round up of none problem related improvements, and while it doesn't answer the question asked is still very good advice

Answer (score 0):

looks like your problem is `pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Draw);` so when the paint event fires the first tick it doesn't do anything on the second tick it repaints once on the 500th tick it repaints 499 times

what you need to do is

```
private void configure()
{
    pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_OnPaint);
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
private void pictureBox1_OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Line line in lines)//array "lines" contains just 16 objects
    {
        //calculating new coordinates ...
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5f), line.P1, line.P2);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P1.X - 2.5f, line.P1.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, line.P2.X - 2.5f, line.P2.Y - 2.5f, 5, 5);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f), line.P1.X, line.P1.Y, 1, 1);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5f), line.P2.X, line.P2.Y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

in a little more detail as you've clearly not understood how event handlers work

`pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_OnPaint);`

reads as when the paint event occurs i want you to call pictureBox1_OnPaint every time you call that command you add an extra instance of that method call to your program so

```
pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_OnPaint);
pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_OnPaint);
```

says that when Paint occurs you want to call pictureBox1_OnPaint twice. it will never trigger the event, calling `Invalidate()` does trigger the event.

so what you need to do is when the form is initialised (this could be the the constructor, an initialise event like (Form.Load) or somewhere similar tell the form what you want it to do with the paint event when it happens with

`pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler( action );`

but only do it once

then on your timer call `Invalidate` so as to trigger the event

as the logic on the tick happens every time the paint event triggers then you might as well just add it into the handers actions instead of going though the lines collection twice